# How to add two objects in a Groovy class list in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I have a Groovy class named MdNote under src folder in a Grails application. I have referenced another class as its property named ReviewOfSystem. In that class I have two object. Now how can I bind this two object property in controller when I bind mdNotes.

I have the following attempts:

MdNote:

```
    class MdNote {
    String ...
    String ....
    List<ReviewOfSystem> reviewOfSystems    
    String ....
}
```

ReviewOfSystems:

```
    class ReviewOfSystem {
    String btnLabel
    String textValue
}
```

In controller:

```
    List reviewOfSystems = Arrays.asList(params.reviewOfSystems.split("\\s*~\\s*"));
List<ReviewOfSystem> rosList = null
reviewOfSystems.each {
            rosList.btnLabel = 'a'
            rosList.textValue = 'b'

        }
```

in controller it shows this tooltip:

> can not assign string to arraylist.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer.

```
List reviewOfSystems = Arrays.asList(params.reviewOfSystems.split("\\s*~\\s*"));
    ArrayList<ReviewOfSystem> ros= new ArrayList<ReviewOfSystem>();
    reviewOfSystems.each {
        String idxValue = it
        ReviewOfSystem reviewOfSystem = new ReviewOfSystem();
        reviewOfSystem.btnLabel = idxValue.substring(0, idxValue.lastIndexOf("^"))
        reviewOfSystem.textValue = idxValue.substring(idxValue.lastIndexOf("^") + 1)
        ros.add(reviewOfSystem);
    }
```